# Binding ContentPresenter.Content to TemplatedParent (WPF/Silverlight)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding, controltemplate, contentpresenter

Basically, I would like to overlay, for example: `TextBlock` over `Button`, by using `ControlTemplate` (applied to this `Button`), but I don't want to get rid of default template of it.

Example:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <TextBlock Text="textBlock" 
                                Margin="10" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Content="button1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and it gives `Button` stripped of it's default template:

[image]

Rather, I would like to receive something like this:

[image]

Is it possible by using `ControlTemplate`? I was trying to bind `TemplatedParent` to  `ContentPresenter.Content` like here:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
        Path=., 
        Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or other combinations, but I couldn't make it work.

**Edit:**

Because I would like to be able to apply this `TextBlock` not only to a button (it was just an example) but to any `Control`, I don't want do it by copying default style (to the resources or somewhere), for every `Control`.
Also, I would prefer not to create `UserControl`, because I would like to keep xaml clean as much as possible (I mean with system Controls) - and just to turn on/off the overlaying `TextBlock` by using a `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the [default style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the button and modify it to add your `TextBlock`. The second option, my preference, is to create a new UserControl that will contain the `Button` and the `TextBlock` with `IsHitTestVisible=False`. You can then add dependency properties to be able to bind to the button and the text block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but those opions will be not good for me. I edited my question, to make it more precise.